# Dynamic Variable PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to update my database. I'm using a loop to display the IDs and values from input boxes. Right now I have:

```
foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <form action="" method ="post">
        <input type="text" name="Name[<?=$row['ID']?>]">
        <input type="hidden" name="NameID[<?=$row['ID']?>]" value="<?=$row["ID"]?>">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="NameEnter[<?=$row["ID"]?>]">
    </form>
<?endforeach?>
```

Which obviously outputs something like Name[1], Name[2], etc.

For my PDO when I go to update it how do I get

```
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$ID = $_POST["ID"];
if(isset($_POST['NameEnter'])) {
$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE Table SET Name = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$update->execute(array($name,$ID));
}
```

It keeps outputting the value of ARRAY instead of the actually typed in value. I assume it has to do with `$name` being looped as the same thing?

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag in there somewhere?

Comment: The names you are giving your inputs are `Name[ID]` and `NameID[ID]`, which will cause the browser to send them back as arrays.  Try using `print_r` or `var_dump` to see what you actually get in the post data.  You might also try dropping the square brackets from the input names, like `name="Name<?=$row['ID']?>"`

Comment: Start with a simple bit of debugging code. Add `print_r($_POST);` at the top of the script so you can see what is being sent to you in the `$_POST` array

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, let me edit that in. Forgot to include that formatting it to fit this.

Comment: @Joe @RiggsFolly It is telling me `array(1) { [1]=> string(3) "Joe" }`

Comment: As I can see, your page will have multiple html-forms like: `<form action...><input type='text' name='Name[1]'><input type='hidden' name='NameID[1]' value='1'><input type='submit' class='button' value='Submit' name='NameEnter[1]></form>` and so on... but I don't understand purpose of this code... All of the forms have only the `ID`.. and - yes.. html-parameters that will send with name via square brackets will be received via php-script as an array, i.e. `url?a[1]=1&a[2]=2` will be accessed via `$_GET['a']` and value will be `array(1=>1, 2=>2)`.

Comment: @Wizard `$_POST` not `$_GET` he is using `method ="post"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was an example...`i.e.` *url?a[1]=1&a[2]=2* `will be accessed via $_GET['a'] and value will be array(1=>1, 2=>2)`. I mean `that GET/POST param name will be an array` , nothing more.. and I agreed with your consider, original code is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each time round that loop you create a seperate form you dont need the complicated naming convention for your input fields

```
foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <form action="" method ="post">
        <input type="text" name="Name">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$row["ID"]?>">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="NameEnter">
    </form>
<?endforeach?>
```

Then its a simple piece of code with easy to figure out field names in the $_POST array.

```
if(isset($_POST['Name'], $_POST['ID'])) {
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE Table SET Name = ? 
                            WHERE ID = ?");
    $update->execute(array($_POST["Name"], $_POST["ID"]));
} else {
    echo 'Missing input';
}
```

Comment: this worked great, thanks. Is there any way to put the `$_POST[""]` into variables or is this just as safe?

Comment: Its not necessary, all that does is duplicate 2 variables and waste memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Syntax: `$stmt->bindValue(':placeholder', $value, PDO::PARAM_TYPE);`

```
$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE Table SET Name = :name WHERE ID = :id");
$update->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute();
```

Comment: Thats another way of doing it, but there is nothing wrong with what he is doing

Comment: Am I mistaken that he was having issues passing the values into the `execute()` statement?

Comment: Yes but that is because he does not realise what the fields are actually called in the `$_POST` array as he has made them unnecessarily complicated. His UPDATE would work if he passed actual data to the `->execute()`

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Totally missed that. Oh well. I'll leave this here incase it will help someone else later.